# after changing _imageFile.png grunt sprite has error

Tags: css, gruntjs, grunt-spritesmith

I changed this image file (_something.png) which is a part of sprite.png. Everything is fine until I change the file with photoshop. 
But I get this error with grunt sprite when I change the image file with photoshop

> (grunt watch is running)
>
> File "public/css/sprites.less" changed.
>
> File "public/img/_cross.png" changed.
>
> Running "sprite:all" (sprite) task
>      Fatal error: Unsupported interlace method.
>      Completed in 1.908s at Thu Jun 11 2015 15:53:09 GMT-0400 (EDT) - Waiting...

Thank you!